# Update constructor using method

Tags: java, oop

I have a game app and I want it to update the constructor `strength` value when I call the `levelUp()` method.

```
public Hero(String heroname, double strength, double strength_gain){
    this.heroname = heroname;
    this.hp = (int) (200+20*strength);
    this.strength_gain = strength_gain;
}

public void levelUp(){
    this.strength = strength + strength_gain;
}
```

But when i do `System.out.println(hero.hp);` after calling `levelUp()` it returns the first value.

Comment: Do you have an instance variable called `strength`? Once the constructor finishes, all of its local variables and arguments are gone. As if they never existed. That variable doesn't exist when `levelUp` gets called.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By the way "updat[ing] the constructor" is not a thing. What do you mean? You mean change the value of a specific member variable?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca They want the hp to update every time strength changes.

Comment: Since you want your `hp` to always be up-to-date and since it does depend on other instance fields, you could create a getter for `hp` (`getHp()`) that would always return an updated value (the calculation is so simple you don't have to cache the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to always get an up-to-date value for a calculation that depends on other variables/inputs is to calculate it on demand (useful for simple calculations, such as the one you have).

EDIT: I realized that you might want to have an `hp` and a `maxHp` if your hero can actually lose/gain `hp` so I edited the example to take that into account.

```
public class Hero {
    // ...
    public int hp;

    public Hero(String heroname, double strength, double strength_gain){
        this.heroname = heroname;
        this.strength = strength; // <-- don't forget to save the initial strength as well
        this.strength_gain = strength_gain;
        this.hp = getMaxHp();
    }

    public int getMaxHp() {
        return (int) (200 + 20 * strength);
    }

    public void levelUp(){
        strength = strength + strength_gain;
        // decide if leveling up also heals your hero?
        hp = getMaxHp();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere in code you can access both the `.hp` and the `.getMaxHp()`.

```
System.out.println(hero.hp);
System.out.println(hero.getMaxHp());
```

If the calculations would be heavy, then using a `boolean` as a change flag and lazily recalculating only once per change and only when required would make more sense.